# A fair division algorithm

Tags: random-variables, fair-division

Imagine two individuals, R and G, are to inherit 100 ancient coins. The coins are perceived to be of somewhat different but unspecified values. By the division 60 coins will go to R and 40 to G. The question is how to come up with a randomized algorithm so that the division will appear fair.

1-What branch of mathematics considers such problems?

2-Can you give precise definitions/solutions/references?

3-Is the following a viable solution? Arrange a bingo game with 100 balls in the container. 60 red and 40 green. In each turn randomly pull a ball, note the color and set it aside. If the color of the pulled ball is red then R will pick a coin of his/her choice. If the color is green then G will pick a coin. Repeat the game with the remining balls until all coins are chosen.

Edits

Resources listed in the comments

[Fair Cake Cutting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_cake-cutting)

[Fair Item Allocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_item_allocation)

Comment: What do you mean by fair ? The inheritors should think it is fair, but the game is in reality rigged ?

Comment: You could call your a example Monte Carlo simulation

Comment: With your random approach, it is possible that one color will show up often enough at the start to give that person a major advantage which cannot be overcome by the greater number of the other color at the end. It is possible to do better than that. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_cake-cutting).